# Squeezing multiple columns in excel to fit into 1 page (a4)

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have around 20 columns in excel which I'd like to print. It'll be in landscape mode. However it wouldn't be able to fit into an a4 size, is it possible to squeeze it in somehow pike having a row in excel show up 2 rows on paper or something?

Comment: Not a programming question. Better suited to Super User.

Comment: What sk you mean

Answer (score 1):

In Excel, click on "File"->"Print Preview" and then select "Setup". You should see the menu in the picture below.

Now select 'Landscape' and 'Fit to:", leave "1 by 1" and click OK. Your entire table should now be printed on one page.

[image: Page Setup Excel]

Comment: I think this is fine, but the thing is it'll make the words really really small, I want it to perhaps move to the next line, so it would be easy on the eyes.

Comment: Well, I guess the quickest way would be to just manually drag the column width to make the columns smaller, then select all column -> right click -> format -> word wrap. That way they fit the width you selected and you can print them as described above.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to file > print there are options around scaling and custom margins. Adjust the margins as necessary and then select the option to fit all columns on one page. Note: this is assuming you are on Excel 2010. I think the same option exists in earlier versions, but may be located somewhere else